# convert free functions to classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, class

I got .aspx pages with functions, as part of re-factoring my code I want to convert them into classes. How can I do this in C#

my functions are like

```
    void onPageLoad(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      if (Page.IsPostBack==true)
      {
          // do something

      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `convert functions into classes` ?

Comment: I want to move functions from .aspx pages to a class such as name.cs file

Comment: anu, then post a more clear code explaining what you want to do. Your question seem like you posted a *random code*

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How do you do it? The same way you'd write any other code. Where do you put these classes? Into a library or app code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23(v=vs.100).aspx (or into .aspx.cs code-behind if you're mixing markup and C# together in the .aspx)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "free function" in C#. Every piece of code is **always** a method/property accesor/constructor member of some class.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you wrote earlier code like:

```
this.Load += this.onPageLoad;
```

or

```
Load += new EventHandler(onPageLoad);
```

You can instead write:

```
var name = new Name();
this.Load += name.onPageLoad;
```

Comment: I don't understand why this has a down vote.  It shows how you can move the Page.Load event to another class.